# Ionic 2/Typescript Mailgun API sends with success but no email ever seems to be sent

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, mailgun, ionic3

I have an Ionic 3 app that has some code that fires an email to a recipient once a certain action is triggered. When I test this in the browser, I get the preflight issue and so I get around this using a Google Chrome plugin that allows me to enable CORS and when I actually execute the function, I get a success that looks like:

```
Headers {
    ok:true,
    status:200,
    statusText:"OK",
    type:2,
    url:"https://api.mailgun.net/v3/https://api.mailgun.net/v3/<my-domain>/messages",
    _body:"Mailgun Magnificent API"
}
```

However, an email is never sent to the address provided. It's not in spam or anything either. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Check these three things :

1) Your URL seems very strange, with nested `https://`. It should be simply `https://api.mailgun.net/v3/<my-domain>/messages`

2) Make sure you validated your Mailgun account before trying to use it

3) Are you in sandbox mode ? If yes, did you add authorized recipients ? If not, you can't send any email.